# Should I use $i or i as array index in Bash Shell?

Tags: bash, shell

```
$ x=(a b c d e)
$ echo ${#x[*]}
5
$ for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo ${x[$i]}; done
a
b
c
d
e
$ for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo ${x[i]}; done
a
b
c
d
e
$ for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo i; done
i
i
i
i
i
$ for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo $i; done
0
1
2
3
4
```

I use either $i or i to access array element, all are right?
Why?

Comment: @For the same reason as explained in the answer, you could also write your loop as `for ((i=0;$i<5;i++)); do ... done`

Answer (score 1):

Array indices are evaluated in an arithmetic context. Which means that both :

```
${x[i]}
```

and

```
${x[$i]}
```

are valid.

For instance :

```
 $ x=(a b c d e)
 $ echo "${x[0]}"
 a
 $ i=1
 $ echo "${x[i+2]}"
 d
```